# What will be the java equivalant code for the following code?

Tags: java, c, assembly, jna, equivalent

I am using JNA to call methods of user32.dll and kernel32.dll. It is working fine as of now. I got stuck in some issue, and I got to know that I have to call this method.

```
void SendCommandToConsole( char* Cmd )
{
    DWORD dwCall = 0x004C1030;
    __asm
    {
        push Cmd;
        push 0;
        call dwCall;
    }
}

SendCommandToConsole ( "rp 2000" );
```

But I am not even getting it what it is? What this __asm is doing ?

Please add appropriate tags, if the tags I have used are not correct. :)

*Edit*
Added .Net and C# tags as suggested.  Above code is in either C# or .NET, may be someone with the knowledge of this language can tell us what actually it is, and how can we do this in java.

Comment: _asm is inline assembly code. It is pushing a pointer to the C equivalent of a String on the stack, terminating it with 0, and then calling the procedure at the dwCall address (I think).

Comment: and this looks like the equivalent of `System.out.println`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks, can we write similar code in java?

Comment: Technically, you could, but you probably don't want to.  JNA can construct callbacks, which are bits of executable written to allocated memory.   You could grab the callback executable address and overwrite it, so that calling the JNA callback would result in your code being executed.  Not recommended unless you *really* understand the assembler code.  Note that your assembly snippet doesn't expose what the compiler is generating with respect to accessing the incoming argument or returning from the (C) call.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal The code snippet presented in your question is *not* C# but plain C. (C# does not allow you to inline assembly.) I have retagged your question accordingly.

Comment: This appears to be a CallOfDuty/ModernWarfare3 hack, so you won't find any help from MSDN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to show what is happening under the hood:

Your call:

SendCommandToConsole ( "rp 2000" );

Is calling the function (SendCommandToConsole) with a parameter of type (char* Cmd).

In the case above, (char* Cmd) equates to the character string (sic) of "rp 2000".

Now what happens under the covers is that higher level languages (Java in your example) need to tell lower level languages how to interpret their instructions in a language that they understand.

So to take the example above of ("I want to call the function "SendCommandToConsole" with the string parameter of "rp 2000"), means that we need to communicate to the lower level language:

- The "uppity-ups want us to run a command". "Oh yea, which one?"
- "They're telling me 'SendCommandToConsole'"
- "Oh, that dude?  He lives at the address '0x004C1030' down here."
- "Oh, you know the dude's address?  Can you deliver this package that
  the uppity-ups want delivered?"
- "Sure thing, but he only accepts packages in a certain order, and
  only of a certain type."
- "No problem, I have their manifest right here... let's see if it
  matches the dude's requirements."

"First off, the dude at that address only wants to know 2 things, and they have to be in order:

- What do you want me do do,
- and who do I report the results to?"

"Ok, that's easy"

I'll assert what I want him to do:

- "Cmd"
- Now I'll assert who I want him to report the results to: "No one (0)"

All right, I'll ring him up... you can go on with your day now.

(Because it is a "void" return, which means you don't care about the result of the transaction)

Answer (score 2):

This means that an assembly code block follows.

dwCall is the pointer to an assembly procedure that takes one argument -> a pointer to a zero terminated array of bytes on the stack. In order to call it properly, you must push the pointer on the stack and you can only do that via assembler.

Comment: There are two arguments being pushed.

Answer (score 2):

In JNA, you can use `Function.getFunction(Pointer)` to obtain an object which you can use to control invocations on a particular address.

```
Function dwCall = Function.getFunction(new Pointer(0x12345678));
String CMD = "SomeCommand";
Integer ARG = new Integer(0);
dwCall.invoke(void.class, new Object[CMD, ARG]);
```

Assuming the function uses the C calling convention, the above code would work.  Ultimately, you would probably want to dynamically look up the function address rather than hard-coding it, and you'd probably want to use a JNA Callback instead of invoking the Function object directly, but the above code provides the bare functionality you are asking for (you should rephrase your original question; you don't want to execute assembly code, you want to call a function at a given address).

Using a JNA Callback mapping will allow you to call the function more naturally.

```
// Use StdCallCallback if the function called uses stdcall rather than cdecl
public class MyCallback extends Callback {
    void invoke(String cmd, int arg);
}

Pointer addr = new Pointer(0x1235678);
MyCallback cb = (MyCallback)CallbackReference.getCallback(MyCallback.class, addr);
cb.invoke("SomeCommand", 0);
```

Note that both of these examples assume that you have already used JNA to load the DLL in question, usually via `Native.loadLibrary()`.

Note also that the signature might actually be `void dwCall(int arg, String cmd)`; cdecl and stdcall conventions push parameters on the stack from right to left, and my thinking isn't clear enough at the moment to map that through properly...

Comment: Thanks @technomage  that looks promising :) . I will try it.

Comment: As Kaito notes, the call sequence appears to be stdcall since there is no stack cleanup after the call.  If it were cdecl, then you'd see the stack adjusted (the equivalent of two 'pop's) after the call.  However, depending on what the compiler does around the ask statements before returning from "SendCommandToConsole", such cleanup may not strictly be required and the writer just forgot the cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Java equivalent, Java doesn't allow such low level control. You need to compile the C code as a DLL and use JNA/JNI to call it.

*Edit 1: The above is only true for assembly code in general. See techomage's reply for calling a stdcall or cdecl function at an address using JNA.*

The __asm block allows you to use assembly in a C source file. The assembly code calls the function at the address 0x004C1030 (whatever function that may be) passing the string by pointer and a zero as arguments.

Calling addresses directly is a bad idea. You probably won't get what you're expecting unless you know the low level internals of your program and your operating system really well. Calling it would most likely crash your program.

Comment: You're focusing on the __asm statement itself rather than the overall result of the full operation.

Comment: We don't know much about the function called. We could just use stdcall since there seems to be no clean up on the caller's side but that's still just hoping it works, it may as well be some other convention.
I do agree that I should've been more explicit and focused on the actual example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not just calling the `SendCommandToConsole()` function?  What that function is doing is making a Windows System call and you should not be writing a function that does that, you should be calling a function that does that.

Comment: actually there is no method like `sendCommandToConsole`, it is just like there is a method at given address, and then to call this method it is named arbitrariy. I guess this is .Net or c# code.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal, perhaps you should at a c# or .NET or windows tag to the question, as once you find out how to call this function from normal Windows programs you should be able to get JNA to map it very easily. You stumbled upon it at too low a level and need a higher level function to provide portable access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the real question is what does "rp 2000" do? If it runs rp.exe with argument 2000 then you can use java.lang.Runtime to do the same thing. If we knew what it did, there might be something in java to do it.

Comment: No, instead of `rp 2000` , you can even say `julian abc` . The real question is how to call a method stored at address `0x004C1030` in a given executable.

Comment: Then perhaps you should rephrase your original question to ask "the real question". :)